# Background hard drive test in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Is there a way for me to perform a stress test of a hard drive as a background process in Linux?

I recently purchased [two 3 TB HDDs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005T3GRLY), installed them in my home Linux server, and they appear to work. BIOS picks them up, partitioned and formatted okay, and SMART reports zero errors.

According to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/84002/how-do-you-stress-test-your-hard-drives), stress tests may indicate failure early in life. If the tests pass, a drive will typically work for several years. I.e., if it makes it past the infant mortality phase, a drive will achieve a ripe old age.

Is there a way I can kick off a stress test, log out, and check back in several days? Something like a daemon that tests disks?

Related questions:
[How to check the health of a hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive)
[How do you stress-test your Hard Drives?](https://superuser.com/questions/84002/how-do-you-stress-test-your-hard-drives)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will destroy existing data:
You could write randomly (`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX bs=1M` etc...) to it, create an empty filesystem (`fdisk /dev/sdX` then `mkfs /dev/sdX1` and tell fsck to check for bad blocks (`fsck /dev/sdX1 -fc`) then re-examine/compare the SMART readout (`smartctl -a /dev/sdX`) between before and after.